# My android app is detected as malware by Avast

Tags: android, malware

I have created an android application, but Avast detects this as malware. Why is this?

Can anyone tell me some more info about this, so I can locate what exactly is considered a virus in this app. This is a very simple app, so I have no idea what might have caused this.

I have reported this as false positive and also contacted avast via their forum. But I guess it wont hurt to post here as well, maybe someone have/had a similar problem.

Comment: can you tell me your app functionality?

Comment: my aop is to upload image in market online like wordpress, ebay, wooCommerce, etsy, facebook and twitter. Do u have solution for this??

Comment: Yes, It may be possible that you aap infected by some malware, Malware infect legitimate code by append malicious code, your app run fine but doesn't terminates immediately, after upload file it may infect/or perform some malicious task

Answer (score 4):

Your app may be detected for several reasons:

- you collect and send remotely private data such as IMEI, IMSI, phone number etc
- your app uploads images online but does not include any EULA and Avast thought you were doing that for malicious purposes
- you are using an aggressive advertisement kit such as StartApp, AirPush etc and that adkit is detected by Avast

Your solutions are:

- contact AVAST and ask them to remove your app's detection. They'll study your app more in depth and decide if it's malicious or not.
- select less aggressive advertisement kits in your app if you want to monetize it. Also consider not monetizing it all if you are just an individual developing for fun. Advertisements pollute devices and in then you won't be getting much money in return, apart if your application is really well known.
- strictly request only permissions you actually use and make sure not to include any libraries that you do not need.